# I need to get last created eligible rider ids and pinged rider ids accordeing to a orderId using a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

[image]

I need to get my data set as this table

[image: order id |eligible riders |ping rider id 100 2,3,4 2,3]

I am trying to get eligible set like this, need to group_concat pinged set also

```
x.id IN (SELECT MAX(x.id) FROM x WHERE ping rider id IS NULL GROUP BY orderId)
```

Comment: Sample data is better presented as [formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362). See [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/81852) for some tips on how to create nice looking tables.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Answer (score 0):

You can assign a group based on the cumulative number of non-null values in `eligible_riders`.  Then aggregate and take the last value:

```
select og.*
from (select order_id, grp, max(eligible_riders) as eligible_riders,
             group_concat(rider_id) as riders,
             row_number() over (partition by order_id order by min(id) desc) as seqnum
      from (select t.*,
                   sum(eligible_riders <> '') over (partition by order_id order by id) as grp
            from t
           ) t
      group by order_id, grp
     ) og
where seqnum = 1;
```

Hmmm . . . You could also do this with a correlated subquery, which might look a bit simpler:

```
select order_id, max(eligible_riders) as eligible_riders,
       group_concat(rider_id) as riders
from t
where t.id >= (select max(t2.id)
               from t t2
               where t2.order_id = t.order_id and
                     t2.eligible_riders <> ''
              )
group by order_id;
```

For performance, you want an index on `(order_id, eligible_riders)`.

Comment: This query takes more than 30 seconds to execute